# Override default language via URL parameter

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

With the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module, is there any way to override the default language selection?

We have a site with two languages, EN and FR, and we'd like to send out an email newsletter that has various links to the secondary (non-default) language content. 
The Language Negotiation is set to "Path prefix with language fallback", and directs them to the default language, even if we use the full language prefixed URL, ie:

```
www.example.com/fr/content
--gets sent to--
www.example.com/en/content
```

What would be ideal is if we could pass an argument like this:

```
www.example.com/fr/content?force_language=FR
```

Any solutions out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been more than a few years since I've done this in Drupal 6, so things may be a bit vague and hazy. I do remember there being an order menu for this, where you could say that language gets selected first by cookie, then browser language, then user preference, then path prefix, or change the order entirely.